# Can I put a MBP (2012)'s hard drive into a Lenovo laptop and continue using MacOS?

Tags: hard-drive

My 15inch 2012MBP has just died. The screen is gone and I want to keep using my old settings but I dont have money to buy a new MB right now. So I'm just wondering what happen if I put my old Apple Hard drive into another laptop that is not a mac. Do I risk losing data or will the OS not load at all?
Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will simply not load at all.
Any non-Apple computer will not even recognise the hard drive's format type without extra software installed.

It is theoretically possible to get a non-Apple computer to boot to macOS/OS X, but it is against Apple's licensing agreement to do so & is consequently off-topic on all of Stack Exchange.
It's also not a trivial task & not guaranteed to work.